# TcpListener in Webapi using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, tcplistener

Is there any sample code or startup documentation about running threads in webapi project. I have group 1 client devices and want them (group 1) to communicate with webapi using tcp communication and have group 2 client devices and want them (group 2) to communicate with webapi using http get/posts. How can i do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I strongly discourage you from doing that. WebApi projects (selfhosted excluded) are controlled by the IIS application pool. That means that the project can get closed/restarted at any time.

In other words: You can not guarantee that your TCP listener keeps running in an IIS project.

It sounds more like you want to use WebSockets to communicate with your users.

Comment: Can I use WebSocket to communicate with a GPS tracking device?

Answer (score 0):

Do you really, really need it?. if you are looking for a "real-time" functionality in your ASP.NET web, you should review SignalR

http://signalr.net/

But, at the other post says, open a tcp listener under IIS is a very bad bad idea.